# Gcm push notification not working if app idle for a long time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed the Android GCM Client tutorial from [Implementing GCM Client](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and the code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/). Also I am using the new process with the help of `GoogleCloudMessaging.register(PROJECT_ID)` to register devices.

The notifications seem to work fine and the ids stored on the server are also consistent.
The problem arises when the app is idle for a long time. The app stops getting any notifications, until it is opened again, after which it starts getting new notifications again (the previous ones are lost though).

Is this a common thing, or am I the only one facing the problem?

**Here's some code for better insight:**
the manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name="GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="myPackage" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="GcmIntentServiceNew" />
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentServiceNew.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

And finally the GcmIntentServiceNew.java

```
public class GcmIntentServiceNew extends IntentService {
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            //
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            //
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // Custom code here 
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

}

**Edit (No Solution yet)**

I tested this a lot and can confirm now that the notifications stop after some time. I've been testing 10-15 notifications after an interval for 5-10 mins, could this be the reason of the notifications stopping?

The only solution that I see is going back to `GCMRegistrar` which is not ideal or reliable either.

Comment: @prtickfdsouza what is the value of this parameter **delay_while_idle** yours server is using? **The value should be set to 'false'** so that device immediately will be receive messages even in a idle mode. By default value of this parameter is 'false'. Also you can test message sending using [my test push server](http://1-dot-sigma-freedom-752.appspot.com/). And I'm not sure that your package name is "myPackage", make sure that you use correct package name of your app in a category attribute in a manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a library called Localytics, which was also handling Push notifications. Nothing related to GCM setup.

Answer (score 0):

The app may be ended by the system if idle too long, but the example registers a `GcmBroadcastReceiver` that is started/invoked by the system whenever a GCM message arrives. That receiver in turn starts a Service which will then create the notification.

This pattern also works if the app is not running - actually, the system launches the app, resp. the broadcast receiver as part of the app, if necessary. If that is not the case with your app, you did something wrong.

Check your manifest file to see if the broadcast receiver and the service are specified correctly.

EDIT : Telling by your manifest file, I think you didn't provide the correct names for the broadcast receiver and the service. You have to provide either the fully qualified class name here (e.g `com.example.GcmBroadcastReceiver`) or you can leave the package name part of your app out but then you'd have at least to provide `.GcmBroadcastReceiver` (mind the leading dot!).

Comment: I am using eclipse for the development and have added the broadcast receiver and the service using the application tab of the manifest file, so I think there might not be a possibility of error in that, also when I tried to do it the way u suggested, I was getting some other error with referencing the specified classes.

Comment: I wouldn't say that using the eclipse plugin rules out the possibility of an error in the manifest - in contrary, but perhaps it's something different. Have you tried to debug your app and check if your GcmBroadcastReceiver is called properly?

Comment: Ok, here's the problem, the GcmBroadcastReceiver is not called on message receive. The deprecated approach of handling GCM message; letting com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver handle the receive and onMessage() process the message, works fine, messages are delayed though.